# A Question on Probability and matrices

Tags: probability

Question:
Let $S$ be the set $\{2, 3, 5, 7, 11\}$. Suppose A and B are two matrices of order 2 each with distinct elements belonging to set $S$. The probability that the matrix $AB$ has at least one even entry is:

My approach:
Instead of finding the possibility of having a matrix with at least one even entry I decided to find the probability of having a matrix with all odd entries and subtract that from one to get the answer. But on hit and trial I've found that it is impossible to have a matrix with all odd elements with the above conditions.

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}k & l\\m & n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}ak+ bm & al + bn\\ck + dm & cl + dn\end{bmatrix}$$

Here when I substituted "a" with 2 and the other variables as any of the distinct elements from the set S. I did get the first row of the resultant matrix with odd elements but the second row were even (obvious from the fact that odd + odd = even). So to turn them into odd numbers I went on to substitute another number from the same matrix with 2 but the question requires you to have distinct elements. So there shouldn't be a fully odd numbered resultant matrix and thus we can conclude that the possibility of having at least one even number in the resultant matrix is one.

But on checking the answer key I find that the answer is not 1 and is actually 0.96
Is there something wrong with my approach? or have I missed something?

It would mean the world to me if someone could simply drop an answer to my doubt instead of editing the font in which I've typed the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :D. I've edited it now

Comment: Could you clarify how the matrices $A$ and $B$ are sampled?

Comment: The matrices are to have their elements from the set S mentioned above and each matrix should have distinct elements

Comment: Values 2,3,5,7 ... or 12, 57,95,123, it is the same. The only question for each number is odd or even. In couple {a,b}, at least one need to be odd, else ak+bm will be even. Same for couples {c,d}, {k,m} and {l,n}. The number of cases is not so big, you can test each of them.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is impossible to get $AB=:C$ to have all odd entries.

We only need to consider the parity of the elements of $S$, that is, $P:=\{0,1,1,1,1\}$.

We can try $A$ having $3$ copies of $1$

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}a+ c & b + d\\a & b\end{bmatrix}$$

and we find that only $B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ can work, and that doesn't fit in $P$. Similarly for other arrangements of $A$.

We can try $A$ having $4$ copies of $1$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}a+ c & b + d\\a+ c & b + d\end{bmatrix}$$

and again $B$ requires $2$ copies of $0$, which doesn't work.